# Proof review: Cartesian product is empty iff one of the product ($X_i$) is empty $\forall 1 \leq i \leq n$ (3.5.8 - Tao, Analysis 1)

Tags: real-analysis

**Claim:**

Let $X_1, ... , X_n$ be sets. The Cartesian product $\prod_{(1\leq i\leq n)} X_i$ is empty if and only if atleast one of $X_i$ is empty.

**Proof:**

W.k.t $\  \prod_{(1\leq i\leq n)} X_i = \bigl\{ (x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n} : x_i \in X_i \ \forall \ 1\leq i \leq n \bigl\}$

\begin{align}
\prod_{(1<i<n)} X_i = \emptyset &\iff \exists \ X_i (x_i \notin X_i) \ \forall \ 1 \leq i \leq n 
\\
&\iff \exists \ X_i (X_i = \emptyset) \ \forall \ 1 \leq i \leq n
\\
&\iff \text{atleast one of $X_i$ is empty}
\end{align}

Please correct me if this proof is wrong or lacking something.
For some reason this proof feels too short.

Thanks for your time!

**Edited as per the directions in the comments:**

\begin{align}
\\
\underline{(1 - \text{direct proof})}
\\
\\
\text{Let} \ (x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n} \ \text{be a tuple}.
\\
\text{Prove that, atleast one of $X_i$ is empty} &\implies \prod_{(1\leq i\leq n)} X_i = \emptyset \\
\exists 1 \leq i \leq n (X_i = \emptyset) &\implies \exists 1 \leq i \leq n (\neg (\exists x_i(x_i \in X_i)))
\\
&\implies \neg(\forall 1 \leq i \leq n (\exists x_i(x_i \in X_i)))
\\
&\implies \neg \exists(x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n} ((x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n} \in \prod_{(1\leq i\leq n)} X_i)
\\
&\implies \prod_{(1\leq i\leq n)} X_i = \emptyset
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\underline{(2 - \text{direct proof})}
\\ \\
\text{Prove that,} \prod_{(1<i<n)} X_i = \emptyset &\implies  \text{atleast one of $X_i$ is empty} \ \forall 1 \leq i \leq n
\\
\prod_{(1\leq i\leq n)} X_i = \emptyset &\implies \bigl\{ (x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n} : x_i \in X_i \ \forall \ 1\leq i \leq n \bigl\} \ = \ \emptyset
\\
&\implies \bigl\{ (x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n} : P((x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}) \} \ = \ \emptyset
\\
\text{where} \ P((x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}) = x_i \in X_i \ \forall \ 1 < i < n
\\
&\implies \forall y (\neg P(y)) \ \text{where} \ y = (x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}
\\
&\implies \forall (x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n} (\exists1 \leq i \leq n (\neg(x_i \in X_i)))
\\
\text{which loosely means,} \ \forall x(\exists i (\neg (x \in X_i)))
\\
&\implies \exists1 \leq i \leq n (X_i = \emptyset) \\ \text{(by Single Choice Axiom)}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\\
\underline{(2 - \text{proof by contrapositive})}
 \\ \\
\text{Prove that, all $X_i$ are non-empty} &\implies \prod_{(1\leq i\leq n)} X_i \not= \emptyset \\
\forall 1 \leq i \leq n (\exists x(x \in X_i)) &\implies \exists (x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n} (\forall 1 \leq i \leq n \ ( x_i \in X_i))
\\
&\implies \exists (x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n} ((x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n} \in \prod_{(1\leq i\leq n)} X_i)
\\
&\implies \prod_{(1\leq i\leq n)} X_i \not= \emptyset
\\
\text{Hence we have, }
\\
\prod_{(1\leq i\leq n)} X_i = \emptyset &\implies \neg (\forall 1 \leq i \leq n (\exists x(x \in X_i)))
\\
&\implies \exists 1 \leq i \leq n (\forall x(x \not\in X_i))
\\
&\implies \text{atleast one of $X_i$ is empty where} \ 1 \leq i \leq n
\end{align}

From (1) & (2), we have

$\prod_{(1\leq i\leq n)} X_i = \emptyset \iff \text{atleast one of $X_i$ is empty where} \ 1 \leq i \leq n$

Please correct me if the above edited proofs lack something (or) can be presented in a better way. Thanks!

Comment: When you say $\exists X_i (x_i \notin X_i)$, where did the variable $x_i$ come from?

Comment: Good question. I want to say that there exist no element in $X_i$ for some $1 \leq i \leq n$. Should i write that as $\exists X_i (\not\exists x (x \in X_i))$ ?

Comment: Or write it as just $\exists X_i (x \not\in X_i)$

Comment: I would say $\exists i \neg \exists x (x \in X_i)$. But to say this is equivalent to $\prod_i X_i$ being empty requires proof.

Comment: @MarkSaving Thanks for the clarity. The point is, if there's an empty set within the product $\prod_{(1\leq i\leq n)} X_i$ then there exist no tuple such that $(x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n} : x_i \in X_i \forall 1 \leq i \leq n$ and hence the product is an empty set. Would this be sufficient or do I miss something?

Comment: That is a partial argument for one direction of the implication - to complete it, you’d have to explain why there can’t be such a tuple. It’s quite simple; if there were such an $x$, then $x_i \in X_i$ which is a contradiction. But you made no attempt to justify the other direction of the iff, which is the nontrivial direction.

Comment: For the other direction, I suggest proving the contrapositive: If all the $X_i$ are non-empty, then so is their product.

Comment: @MarkSaving, PaulSinclair
Thanks a lot for your hints. I've added more thought-out proofs to the question on a new section. I'm still not sure whether the proofs  are correct, (2-direct proof) for example.
Please point out if I'd made any mistakes and extremely sorry about the verbosity -- that's the side-effect of me making sure to not fall for intuitiveness.
Would be happy to hear your thoughts either on the correctness of the proofs (or) any helpful suggestions that'll help me in future proof writing. Can't thank you enough! :)